# Is it haram to build a temple management software application?

Tags: halal-haram, money, work, software

I am looking for a job change, I had an interview and got the offer letter.

The project for which they're hiring me is a temple management system, I'm feeling that it is haram to work on it, but I don't have a clarity suppose what if I only work on writing the programs and processing the data and rendering the information or any images of temples on this website without creating the content will it be considered as haram too.

I'm not a designer so I won't create any images but I may need to use the images provided by others in the website & they may ask me to add/modify some content such as textual data about a temple or anything related to it.

Should I take the risk of trying for this 1 year contract job or just try to be more happy about my current full-time employee job. My parents said not to go for contract job.

The risk factor seems to me like committing haram, earning haram money and my company may not release me in a week and future employer or I need to buy out my notice period I assume they can ask anywhere from 50,000 to 1,50,000 INR.

Update:

I think it is haram because I would be working towards the development of temples because they are symbolize beliefs in multiple Gods or that there is other God than Allah.

I would be creating the web page so I may need to write a program to render the images or information of temples and pictures of the deities they believe in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spoken with an Imam and Mufti about this.

They said that this will have an affect in the afterlife for me, they told that this should be avoided.

They said if I'll be creating a website for managing temples or I'll be sharing/transferring data it is wrong even if I won't be creating any of it but only writing a software to manipulate that it is still wrong.

They said that we should be the one to bring them close to Allah and not work towards the improvement of temples.

The Imam added "By looking at muslims they should feel the greatness of islam and their hearts moving towards islam and accepting islam".

So based on all the things I went through, I decided not to take up this job offer and I turned it down, I've decided to continue in my current job until I find a better job.

Answer (score 3):

As you are clearly, and Openly Helping, Participating and promoting the False Gods (deities) then without any doubt it should be avoided (i cannot say it is haram as i am not a scholar to give fatwa on it, but in my opinion stay faaar away from it.

Someone also said that your intentions are good, so its ok. i would say that it is like drinking alcohol saying "i have no bad intentions drinking it" or doing Zina and saying "i am doing it with good intentions, so its not haram"