# Is it halal to supply building matterials to build a temple?

Tags: halal-haram, other-religions

I am a building materials supplier and I got a tender from our government to supply materials on demand to build a temple. But I am not sure if this is haram or halal?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking your time to learn more about our site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and visiting the [help].

Comment: This post has some relevance http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35488/is-it-haram-to-build-a-temple-management-software-application. I'd say once you know the purpose or use for the material you are at least partly involved. In that case it is rather frowned upon or even considered as haram unless you are in a non-Muslim country in that case at least you are asked to fulfill your contracts http://legacy.quran.com/5/1...

Answer (score 2):

Surah Al-Maidah , Ayah # 2:

> تعاونوا على البر والتقوى ولا تعاونوا على الإثم والعدوان
>
> Cooperate in righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and
>   and transgression

Building a temple where shirk happens and idols are worshiped is sin and transgression. Shirk is actually the biggest sin.